# Ubuntu 20.04 - installation media created with gddrescue from official iso not working on Lenovo Thinkpad

Tags: software-installation

I did:

```
sudo apt install gddrescue
sudo fdisk -l
ddrescue ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso /dev/sda --force -D
```

After boot I see

```
/boot/ file not found
```

Comment: 1. Did you really want to install the live system to the first drive `/dev/sda`? 2. But this time I think you were saved by not using `sudo` for the cloning command line, because you need elevated permissions to write to block devices. Or did you use `sudo` for that command and overwrote the internal drive? -- It is risky to use `dd` and `ddrescue` for this purpose. I would recommend the **Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator** or **Disks** alias `gnome-disks` or [**mkusb**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) to clone in a safe way.

Comment: Canonical/Ubuntu recommend you make a LiveUSB following these instructions on another Linux PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu or on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows after checking for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu - A) Why use that _ddrescue_ method? B) Which model of ThinkPad? What's the modl part number from the serial number sticker? Please add to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment